Autodesk Forge Search
GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/search
The docs (https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/filtering/) say

The only true indication that you have reached the last page is if a
link for the next page (meta.links.next) is missing from the end of
the page.

If you disable pagination you get fast but incomplete results, whereas with pagination File search is far too slow (minutes). It returns the results spread out over up to 50 pages that are mostly empty.
Also it doesn’t find duplicates when searching by "filter[name]-starts"
Also the filter[hidden]=true seems to have no effect.
( The ACC web page is obviously using a different API that returns results in pages of 100. This has another glitch - it sometime returns results that do not match the search string.)
Any ideas would be welcome.
